# Tensorflow 1.x with cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.1

Tags: tensorflow, build

Is it possible to build tf 1.x (like v1.14.0) with cuda 11.2. I was checking [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and know that originally we need to use cuda 10.0. But based on hardware limitation, we need to use 11.2 or greater, and on another side, my model is in tf 1.x.

So my question is: Has anyone built TensorFlow 1.x with cuda 11.2?

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Shokouhi Gol, Tensorflow is very specific with its build configuration to be supported. As mentioned in the link, You need to either upgrade the tensorflow version 2.5 - 2.11 for CUDA 11.2 or need to change the CUDA version to 10.0 to be compatible with Tensorflow 1.x.